# How can I hide a div in all instances of a component while I open it my current target

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm showing a div on click from a child component. The component is rendered multiple times on the page outside any kind of loop. When I show the div in this specific instance of the component I want to hide it in all others. I've tried using a `ref` to close all instances with DOM manipulation, but that didn't work.

```
 <template>
  <span>
    <div class="options--small" @click="toggleOptions" />
    <div v-show="showOptions" ref="test" class="options-menu">
      <slot />
    </div>
  </span>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'ShowOptions',
  data () {
    return {
      showOptions: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleOptions () {
      this.$refs.test.style.display = 'none'
      this.showOptions = !this.showOptions
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely should not be using `ref` or accessing the DOM directly; that is always a last resort.

The visibility of each options menu is controlled by the `showOptions` property of the respective component. You need a way of communicating to every component instance that you want them to hide their menu. This can be achieved by using an event bus. It's usually a good idea to have an implementation of this for every Vue project so that you can perform decoupled inter-component communication.

If you're using Vue 2 then a Vue instance can be used as an event bus.

Untested:

```js
// event-bus.js

const v = new Vue()

export function on(event, fn) {
  v.$on(event, fn)
}

export function off(event, fn) {
  v.$off(event, fn)
}

export function emit(event, ...args) {
  v.$emit(event, ...args)
}
```

```js
import * as bus from './event-bus.js'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showOptions: false
    }
  },
  created() {
    bus.on('ShowOptions.hide', this.onShowOptionsHide)
  },
  destroyed() {
    // Important otherwise leaks memory
    bus.off('ShowOptions.hide', this.onShowOptionsHide)
  },
  methods: {
    onShowOptionsHide() {
      // Hide our options menu when other menu shows theirs
      this.showOptions = false
    },
    toggleOptions() {
      if (this.showOptions) {
        this.showOptions = false
      } else {
        // Tell other components to hide their options menu
        bus.emit('ShowOptions.hide')
        this.showOptions = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't want to use an event bus then you can keep track of every component instance in order to hide their menus.

Untested:

```js
const instances = new Set()

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      showOptions: false
    }
  },
  created() {
    instances.add(this)
  },
  destroyed() {
    instances.delete(this)
  },
  methods: {
    hideOtherMenus() {
      for (const i of instances) {
        if (i !== this) {
          i.showOptions = false
        }
      }
    },
    toggleOptions() {
      this.hideOtherMenus()
      this.showOptions = !this.showOptions
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The event bus solution is neat. Learned something today. Thanks for your help!